# Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'. org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, grails, groovy

I have an issue with starting my project after the upgrade of IDEA. 
Current error is the following:

```
CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 2s
|Running application...
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1118)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1098)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:645)


1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

If I try to clean and run-app I get the following:
| Running application...
<-------------> 0% WAITING

> IDLE
>   startup failed:
>   General error during semantic analysis: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Tried everything I know, project settings, clean cache, invalidate cache and restart...  nothing is helping.

Comment: https://github.com/julienvollering/MIAmaxent/issues/1 maybe?

Comment: Tried already, after that only one line disappeared:Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Comment: Mainly this is the issue and I cannot find anything on that:
> IDLE
startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder

Comment: Do you have spring security in your dependencies?

Comment: Yes I do have Spring boot and sprint security - core and web

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.encoding.BCryptPasswordEncoder - using deprecated classes

```
class CryptoEncoderWrapper implements org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder
```

you need to change build.gradle to:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.0'
```

BCrypt now has this import

`import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder`

Now, this issue is resolved but leads to other issues.